# WordPress Filter custom post type by multiple taxonomies

Tags: wordpress, filter, plugins, categories

I wrote a  category plugin that filters categories based on which category a user clicks on. I am trying to modify it to work with two categories together. What am I doing wrong?

index.php:

```
/*Load Dependent Scripts
===*/
function cf_load_scripts() { 
    wp_enqueue_style( 'add-mtncf-css', plugins_url('/css/style.css', __FILE__) );
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'add-mtncf-custom-js', plugins_url('/js/custom.js', __FILE__) );
    wp_localize_script( 'add-mtncf-custom-js', 'ajax_params', array('ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php')));
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cf_load_scripts');


/*Get the Categories and Display them using a Shortcode
===*/
function cf_get_cats($atts) {

        $args1 = array(
               'taxonomy' => 'ir_projectss_cat',
               'orderby' => 'name',
               'order'   => 'ASC'
           );       
        $args2 = array(
               'taxonomy' => 'ir_projectss_state',
               'orderby' => 'name',
               'order'   => 'ASC'
           );
        
    $categories = get_categories($args1);
        $states = get_categories($args2);
    
        /*loop through categories*/
        $output1 .= '<div class="cf-category-holder"><div class="cf-category-title">Sort by Category</div>';
          foreach($categories as $category) : 
            $output2 .= '<div class="cf-category-list"><a class="cf-category-list-item" href="#!" data-slug="'. $category->slug .'" data-taxonomy="ir_projectss_cat">
                 '.$category->name.'
              </a><span class="cf-category-count">'.$category->count . '</span></div>';
          endforeach; 
        $output3 .= '</div>';   

        /*loop through states*/
        $output4 .= '<div class="cf-category-holder"><div class="cf-category-title">Sort by State</div>';
          foreach($states as $state) : 
            $output5 .= '<div class="cf-category-list"><a class="cf-category-list-item" href="#!" data-slug="'. $state->slug .'" data-taxonomy="ir_projectss_state">
                 '.$state->name.'
              </a><span class="cf-category-count">'.$state->count . '</span></div>';
          endforeach; 
        $output6 .= '</div>';   

        /*display categories and states*/
        $output = $output1 . $output2 . $output3 . $output4 . $output5 . $output6;
        return $output;

}
add_shortcode('mtn-cf-cats','cf_get_cats');


/*Get the Posts and Display them using a Shortcode
===*/
function cf_get_posts($atts) {

        /*query to get posts*/
      $latest = new WP_Query(
          array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'paged' => 1,
            'post_type' => 'ir_projectss',
        )
         );
    
        /*loop through posts*/
        if($latest->have_posts()):
          $output4 .= '<div class="cf-parameters"><div class="cf-inactive cf-selected-category">Selected Category: <span></span></div><div class="cf-inactive cf-search-terms">Search Term: <span></span></div></div><div class="cf-post-grid"><div class="cf-load-post">Loading...</div>';
            while($latest->have_posts()) : $latest->the_post();
                    $id = get_the_ID();
                    $cats = get_the_category($id);
              require('includes/data.php');
            endwhile;
          $output6 .= '</div>';
        endif;
          
        wp_reset_postdata();

        /*display posts*/
        $output =  $output4 . $response . $output6;
        return $output;

}
add_shortcode('mtn-cf-posts','cf_get_posts');


/*AJAX PHP Query to show posts for load more link and category links
===*/
function cf_filter() {
        $catSlug = $_POST['category'];
        $stateSlug = $_POST['state'];
        

        $ajaxposts = new WP_Query([
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'paged' => $_POST['paged'],
            'post_type' => 'ir_projectss',
                'tax_query'   => [
            'relation' => 'AND',
                [
                    'taxonomy' => 'ir_projectss_cat',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => $catSlug
                ],
                [
                    'taxonomy' => 'ir_projectss_state',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => $stateSlug
                ]
            ]
        ]);

        /*loop through clicked on load more link and category links*/
        if($ajaxposts->have_posts()) {
            while($ajaxposts->have_posts()) : $ajaxposts->the_post();
                require('includes/data.php');
            endwhile; 
        } else {
            $response .= '<div class="cf-no-results">No results found.</div>';
        }

      /*display ajax results*/
        $result = [
            'max' => $max_pages,
            'html' => $response,
        ];

        echo json_encode($result); 

      exit;
}
add_action('wp_ajax_cf_filter', 'cf_filter');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_cf_filter', 'cf_filter');

?>


custom.js:
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    /*category filter*/
    jQuery('.cf-category-list-item').on('click', function() {
        
        /*show selected category message*/
        jQuery('.cf-selected-category span').text(jQuery(this).data('slug'));
        jQuery('.cf-selected-category').removeClass("cf-inactive");
        
        /*remove hyphen from category slug*/
        value = jQuery('.cf-selected-category span').text();
        jQuery('.cf-selected-category span').text(value.replace(/\-/g, " "));
    });
    
    /*hide Selected Category message when clicking on View All Posts*/
    jQuery('.cf-category-list-last').on('click', function() {
        jQuery('.cf-selected-category').addClass("cf-inactive")
    });
    
    /*ajax for category filtering*/ 
    jQuery('.cf-category-list-item').on('click', function() {
        jQuery('.cf-category-list-item').removeClass('active');
        jQuery(this).addClass('active');
              jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: ajax_params.ajax_url,
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                  action: 'cf_filter',
                  category: jQuery(this).data('slug'),
                  state: jQuery(this).data('slug'),
                }, 
                beforeSend: function() {
                jQuery('.cf-load-post').addClass('cf-active');
                jQuery('.cf-post-grid').addClass('cf-inactive');
                    },
                success: function (res) {
                jQuery('.cf-post-grid').html(res.html);
                    //console.log(jQuery(this).data('slug'));
                },
                complete: function() {
                    jQuery('.cf-load-post').removeClass('cf-active');
                    jQuery('.cf-post-grid').removeClass('cf-inactive');
                    }
              })    
    });

    
});
```

This works fine for one taxonomy, but when I add a second one, it just loads and says no results available. What am I doing wrong?